# AbstractApplicationContext vs ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

what is the difference between `AbstractApplicationContext` and `ApplicationContext`  ?
can we call

```
context.registerShutdownHook()
```

using `ApplicationContext`?

I saw this while going through a sample code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    context.registerShutdownHook();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same as the diff between abstract class (AbstractApplicationContext ) and an interface (ApplicationContext).

**Can we call context.registerShutdownHook() using ApplicationContext?**

No, because `registerShutdownHook()` is part of `ConfigurableApplicationContext` interface which is not extended by `ApplicationContext`

Answer (score 9):

registerShutdownHook() gracefully shutdowns bean and preform finalization like calling the destroy methods. This is the method declared in the interface ConfigurableApplicationContext which is implemented by AbstractApplicationContext,and it is not implemented by ApplicationContext.So the invokation of registerShutdownHook() only possible from the AbstractApplicationContext's object

Answer (score 2):

registerShutdownHook() is not part of ApplicationContext. So, we can not use Application context.

This method can be invoked using references using with either ConfigurableApplicationContext or AbstractApplicationContext.

As methods can be called either from interface or class having the implementation. Because, we actually create object for ClassPathXmlApplicationContext using the reference of AbstractApplicationContext.

Difference: 
ConfigurableApplicationContext is an interface where the methods are implemented in AbstractApplicationContext class.