# Junit - loading Spring XML config through annotations

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel, cxf

I am working with Camel 2.15.2, Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE, CXF 3.0.4, Junit 4.12.

When I run the following **test**, loading the Spring application context fails:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations=
            {
                "classpath:com/me/someFile.xml",
                "classpath:META-INF/spring/someFile.xml"
            })
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport
{
    //...
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find RouteContext with id someRoute
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteContextRefDefinitionHelper.lookupRoutes(RouteContextRefDefinitionHelper.java:65)
```

But when I run this test, the Spring application context loads successfully:

```
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport
{
    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext()
    {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]
                {
                    "classpath:com/me/someFile.xml",
                    "classpath:META-INF/spring/someFile.xml"
                });
    }

    //...
}
```

Why does it fail in the first case?

Aren't these two ways to load the Spring application context equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried not to extend `CamelTestSupport` when using annotations?

Comment: @Ralf No because 1. I would like to use many of its cool methods in my test 2. If it matters then it's still not an expected behavior, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is the same as this question. [AbstractApplicationContext versus ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851829/abstractapplicationcontext-vs-applicationcontext)  Without seeing your actual context files it would be hard to see exactly why the more strict `ApplicationContext` implementation required by the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation is failing.  Hope this helps!